# Java: Concurrent queue with long-lived consumers and processing guarantees for short-lived producers

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

I am looking for an existing implementation for a concurrent queue that can be used to implement a typical producer-consumer pattern with the following caveat. Each producer is short-lived but before exiting has to block until all the messages it put on the queue have been processed by the consumers. Consumer and the queue are long-lived.

Some ideas I've had were around either using a single partitioned queue where each partition is assigned to a producer or have a dedicated queue for each producer and build a sort of composite queue on top of producer queues which will be used by the consumers.

This seems like this would be a common pattern for http servers which have numerous http threads which would act like producers to the queue and a fixed number of worker threads which would act like consumers of the queue. The http threat will then block until the work it enqueue is completely processed by the consumers before returning http response to the http client.

Answer (score 2):

> Each producer is short-lived but before exiting has to block until all the messages it put on the queue have been processed by the consumers. Consumer and the queue are long-lived.

`Stream.parallelStream()` does this. It is a common pattern which can be solved a few ways e.g. ExecutorService.submit(task) + Future.get().

> build a sort of composite queue on top of producer queues

I would try to make it as simple as possible.

What works best depends on the workload of your tasks. e.g. is it CPU or IO bound.

> pull 1000 messages off the queue, process messages, notify producers of the messages processed successfully;

```
List<Message> toProcess = someSourceOfMessages(1000);
toProcess.parallelStream().forEach(m -> process(m));
// do something after all tasks are complete.
```

Comment: Not sure when you suggest calling Stream.parallelStream() if data is being continuously produced to the queue as producers come and go (when their data has been consumed) and consumers pull data off the queue continuously. Imagine producers A and B asynchronously call enqueue(itemA1), enqueue(itemB1), enqueue(B2), enqueue(A2). Then producer A can exit only after both A1 and A2 are consumed and B can exit only after both B1 and B2 are consumed. So, there would have to be some sort of async notification from the queue that would tell producers when their data has been consumed.

Comment: @alecswan you want to wait until the jobs are consumed, rather than when they are processed.  What is the reason for waiting for consumption esp as the task could die or take any amount of time to process?

Comment: @alecswan `Stream.parallelStream` is only useful for waiting for the tasks to be processed where producers and their tasks are relatively short lived.

Comment: consider a service that pulls messages off several source Kafka topics and publishes them to a target Kafka topic, possibly in a different Kafka cluster; so, our queue would maintain messages that have been pulled off Kafka topics and remain to be published to Kafka; note that in this case producers to our queue are actually consumers of source Kafka topics and can only commit offsets when their data was dequeued an published to Kafka by our queue consumers (which publish messages to target Kafka topics)

Comment: @alecswan that works provided your publishers have guaranteed delivery, in memory, queue don't have this so you have to wait until the data is processed or you are not really guaranteeing the task will be processed i.e. if it dies after the message is taken from the queue but before it is completely processed.

Comment: I must have miscommunicated because the intent is for the work pulled off the queue to be fully processed before notifying producers; so, consumer's control flow could look like this: wake up, pull 1000 messages off the queue, process messages, notify producers of the messages processed successfully; in fact, I ended up implementing something like this with a single ArrayBlockingQueue and Guava EventBus which allows consumers notify producers about the messages successfully processed

Comment: @alecswan an ExecutorService or a Stream.parallelStream() will do the same thing, though it will wait for the task to be complete and will notify the producer if an Exception occurs.